# Shared data location for Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, qt, application-data

On Windows, there is a standard location for application data that is shared in common with all users on the machine (i.e. in Vista/7, `(root):\ProgramData`). I'm looking for a way to get such a folder on other platforms using Qt.

- Does Qt provide a built-in method for doing this? ([QDesktopServices](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopservices.html#StandardLocation-enum) looked promising, but does not seem to provide this option.)
- If not, what are the standard locations on Linux and Mac OS X systems for shared application data? Is `/usr/share` the correct place? Is there a standard at all?

**[CLARIFICATION]** This is for mutable data.

Comment: Excellent question - this is the kind of small detail that a lot of cross-platform developers don't consider / want to just go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if Qt provides an API for that. Here's the OS X specific information.

On OS X, it depends whether it's a GUI app or unix level support libraries.  For a GUI app, it's the standard practice to have all the read-only data shared by all users inside the app bundle itself. Typically you have

```
  YourApp.app/
  YourApp.app/Contents
  YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS
  YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YouApp      .... this is the binary
  YourApp.app/Contents/Resources/        .... here are all the shared data
```

The GUI presents the directory `YourApp.app` as the application itself, so that you can copy/move it around without any problem.
If that's not possible, it's recommended to use the subdirectory of

```
/Library/Application Support/name_of_your_app/
```

for data shared among users.

It's a bad idea to have a mutable, shared data among users on a machine; in general it's impossible due to the access restrictions. Note that a standard user might not have, and in fact usually does not have an administrative right to write into a shared location.

For mutable data specific to a user, use

```
~/Library/Application Support/name_of_your_app/
```

See [this Apple guideline](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/LibraryDirectory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002282-BAJHCHJI) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The [File System Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) suggest that `/usr/share` should be used for [read-only architecture independent data files](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE26), and `/var/lib` should be used for [state information pertaining to an application or the system](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION).

You didn't specify whether you're referring to read-only or mutable state, but the wording of your question (specifically the comparison to `%COMMONAPPDATA%`) suggests mutable state, in which case `/var/lib` would be appropiate. Don't forget to have a user group with write rights to your subdirectory there available (or created by the package installation script) and have the sysadmin add the appropiate users to that group.

Comment: Various directories under /var may be what you are looking for.  The output of <code>man hier</code> describes the file hierarchy in some detail.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS, one solution is to use the /Users/Shared directory, since it is read/write for all users, and is therefore mutable for everyone. Have to make sure any files you create in there are read/write for everyone too.

Or you can use app support as suggested by others, and making any files you need to be mutable read/write for everyone, but that means an admin needs to create them first, either through an installer or first run, which is a little ugly.

My company is using Users/Shared for exactly this purpose, but I don't know how "neat" it is considered.